# Same set of carboxylate reagents yielding two different products with an alkylide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, erratum, nucleophilic-substitution

I recently came across **two contrasting products for the same set of reagents** - carboxylic acid and alkyllithium, and wish to understand why exactly any difference exists between the two.

**Reaction 1**

[image]

**Reaction 2**

[image]

I understand that in steps **A**, **B**, and **E**, the alkylide (hydride in **E**) is acting as a base and abstracting the acidic proton. I'm fine with that.

However, compare step **C** and **F**. Both involve the same reagents (carboxylate and an alkylide). In step **C**, nucleophilic addition of the ethylide has taken place on the carbonyl group, which is a reasonable step according to me. However, in step **F**, an ester has been formed instead. I am unable to grasp how an ester can *even* form in this condition (considering both ethylide and carboxylate are negatively charged), and even if it can form, why wasn't it formed in **C** as well?

---

**Source:** MS Chouhan; Advanced Problems In Organic Chemistry; 11th ed; Q64 and 27 in Alcohol, Ethers and Epoxides

Comment: There has to be a mistake somewhere. Based on charge conservation, the $\ce{Li}$ ends up associated with the counterion, $\ce{Li^+}$, i.e. a $\ce{Li2}$ molecule gets formed, which I believe has only been observed in the gas phase.

Comment: @ralk912 Yes, that's reasonable. So, you're suggesting that reaction 1 is correct, and reaction 2 is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I don't see anyway reaction 2 would be right.

Comment: Step F has to be wrong. I suspect it is a typo and should be MeI

Comment: @Waylander There isn't any iodine here...

Comment: @GaurangTandon  I mean that the reagent should be MeI instead of MeLi as currently written

Comment: @Waylander oh, great. That could definitely be the intended case of the author. Thanks! :)

Comment: The product of F is cyclohexylmethyl ketone. The same reaction as in Reaction 1. Reviewed by Margret Jorgensen in Organic Reactions.

Comment: @user55119 Thanks for getting that data! I updated my answer below accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @Waylander: see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

**Reaction 2 is wrong. Reaction 1 is correct.**

Later in the book (q87), another question is asked with the same set of reagents (carboxylic acid and methyllithium). Reaction 1 has been used in that as well.

Reaction 2 is wrong because, as ralk912 [noted above](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92371/same-set-of-carboxylate-reagents-yielding-two-different-products-with-an-alkylid#comment169890_92371), charge conservation has to be followed. If methyl lithium reacts with a negatively charged species, the product has to be negatively charged as well. If the ester is neutral, then lithium must be negatively charged, and would associate with the $\ce{Li+}$ formed in step **E** to form $\ce{Li2}$, which is only observed in gas phase.

Not to forget that there simply isn't any mechanism wherein a carboxylate would react with an alkylide to form an ester. It does not simply occur. Reaction 2 is wrong.

---

Waylander [has suggested](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92371/same-set-of-carboxylate-reagents-yielding-two-different-products-with-an-alkylid?noredirect=1#comment169918_92371) a good reason for a misprint i.e. the reagent $\ce{CH3Li}$ might have been intended to be $\ce{CH3I}$ instead. Then, it would make sense for the carboxylate anion to attack an alkyl halide, and displace an iodide ion (which could easily attach with the $\ce{Li+}$ ion to form lithium iodide) forming the methyl ester.

---

[user55119 has confirmed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92371/same-set-of-carboxylate-reagents-yielding-two-different-products-with-an-alkylid?noredirect=1#comment169959_92371) that the product of the step **F** is cyclohexylmethyl ketone, and that it is obtained by reaction 1 only. The book containing this is "Margret Jorgensen in Organic Reactions."

Comment: Maybe add that cyclohexyl methyl ketone would form after aqueous workup, as in Reaction 1.

Comment: @ralk912: The geminal bis-lithium alkoxide is implicit from reaction 1. Its stability is the reason the methyl ketone is not formed, and over reacts with methyllithium, prior to addition of water.

Comment: @user55119 I'm afraid I don't follow?

Comment: If the product of C were not stable in solution, it would collapse to Li2O and a ketone. The ketone would react with methyllithium to form a tertiary alcohol. The same is true of F. Read "Reaction of Organolithium Reagents with Carboxylic Acids",  Margaret J. Jorgenson ,Vol.18, in Organic Reactions.

Comment: But I never said it is not stable. I actually say that to get the ketone back from the geminal dialkoxide, an acidic workup is needed.